# Angular Universal Node.js - System is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-universal

I created an Angular 2 / Angular Universal app with lazy-loading routes like so:

```
{
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './+app/+home/home.module#HomeModule'
},
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

When I navigate to `localhost` in the browser, it redirects to `/home` and everything works properly. But whenever I enter `localhost/home` in the browser with a hard reload, my Node.js terminal throws an error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: System is not defined
ReferenceError: System is not defined at 
SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (...@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7151:20)
```

It seems to render the view correctly though.

When I change my route to use the non-lazy-load way, the error goes away:

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
}
```

But I want to use lazy-loading in my app.
In my HTML, I use SystemJS to import the client app:

```
<script>
    System.import('./client.js')
        .then(function(m) {
            console.log("Welcome");
        });
</script>
```

My Dependencies:

```
"@angular/common": "2.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
"@angular/core": "2.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
"@angular/http": "2.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
"@angular/router": "3.1.2",
"@angularclass/bootloader": "1.0.1",
"angular2-express-engine": "2.1.0-rc.1",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.0",
"angular2-universal": "2.1.0-rc.1",
"angular2-universal-polyfills": "2.1.0-rc.1"
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: I eventually cloned the official [Angular Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) repo and threw out all I didn't need. I noticed some code in there defining System, so this was solved by using that official repo.

Comment: @Nicky - I'm currently running into this issue. Do you happen to remember where the code for defining System was?

Comment: @Randy From the official Universal Starter Repo, there is a file `src/typings.d.ts` defining System (see [here](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/src/typings.d.ts#L36)). I recommend you use this file in your repo. The accompaying code for e.g. lazy routing is found [here](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/src/%2Bapp/app-routing.module.ts#L4). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @Nicky. I already have those typings definitions so I'm not sure what the issue is. Once I get time I'll make a barebones repo and see if it reproduces.